# Why "desfallecer" does not mean "to resucitate"?

Tags: prefijos

*Des* is a prefix that indicates a negative (the contrary of). This is evident in [so many](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Spanish_terms_prefixed_with_des-) Spanish words. Trivial examples: *desobedecer*, *destapar*, *desordenar*, *descolgar*.

For some reason, *desfallecer* does not mean the opposite of *fallecer*, but "to become weak". One would expect for it to mean "to come alive, to resuscitate". Or at least it should mean "to become stronger", the opposite of what it means.

Why is this the case? Is this a unique "misuse" of this prefix or there is a linguistic reason?

Comment: [to become weak]. You can disobey, uncover, disorder and unhook but you can undie. That's why. Of course, it is not a misuse. fallecer is not just to die. You can go look it up in the RAE.

Comment: We also have examples in English like flammable/inflammable where the negative prefix in- has no effect.

Comment: @mdewey That's a misunderstanding. That is **not** the negating prefix *in-* in *inflammable*. It's a different *in-* prefix, the one you can see being used in *inflame*.  So *inflammable* means **able to be *inflamed***. It does not mean, for lack of a better word, "un-flammable". So that's why *flammable* and *inflammable* amount to the same thing, not because some negative prefix anomalously  "doesn't count".

Answer (score 1):

Porque en latín también se daba exactamente la misma multiplicidad de significados con el prefijo **dis-**. Buscá primero en la [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/des-#CJuPwUn), a ver qué tiene para decir:

> des-
> Confluencia de los prefs. lats. de-, ex-, **dis-** y a veces e-.
>
> 1. pref. Denota negación o inversión del significado de la palabra simple a la que va antepuesto. *Desconfiar, deshacer*.
> 2. pref. Indica privación. *Desabejar*.
> 3. pref. **Indica exceso o demasía. *Deslenguado*.**
> 4. pref. Significa 'fuera de'. *Descamino, deshora*.
> 5. pref. A veces indica afirmación. *Despavorido*.

Ahora, consultamos el [Wikcionario](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dis-#Latin) a ver qué nos dice:

> Latin
> Alternative forms: dī- dif-
> Etymology
> From Proto-Italic *dwis-, from Proto-Indo-European *dwís. Cognate with Ancient Greek δίς (dís), Sanskrit द्विस् (dvis). Doublet of bis.
>
> Prefix dis-
>
> 1. asunder, apart, in two
>    *dīmittō ― dismiss, disband*
>    *discēdō ― part, separate*
> 2. reversal, removal
>    dissimulō ― disguise, conceal\
> 3. **utterly, exceedingly**
>    **differtus ― stuffed full**

La cuestión viene desde hace bastante. Y las etimologías anteriores al latín en general son hipotéticas, así que más ciencia que ésta no creo que sea posible hallar.

Answer (score 0):

> La idea de que fallecer solo se aplica a la muerte natural probablemente sea influencia de desfallecer (‘perder el aliento y las fuerzas’), pero en la actualidad **son voces distintas con sentidos que carecen de relación directa** (aunque tengan un origen común).

<sub>*Source [https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/fallecer-vs-morir/#:~:text=La%20idea%20de%20que%20fallecer,aunque%20tengan%20un%20origen%20com%C3%BAn](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/fallecer-vs-morir/#:%7E:text=La%20idea%20de%20que%20fallecer,aunque%20tengan%20un%20origen%20com%C3%BAn)).*</sub>

Comment: https://dle.rae.es/desfallecer?m=form&m=form&wq=desfallecer